# How to print the stack trace of the java side from a core file

Tags: java, debugging, gdb, jdb, jstack

I have a program written in C++, it will use JNI to launch a JVM and run the java code. But now the program crashed and generate a core file.

When I attach the core with the gdb by `gdb <my_program> , only the top two frames are shown, and others are ??

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f635bf98596 in __memmove_avx_unaligned () from /var/lib/jenkins/Projects/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f634aa1d142 in Unsafe_CopyMemory0 () from /RELEASE/BIN/Linux/_jre/lib/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007f63285c20a4 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000000014ea in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000b5330948 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I think those ?? are java stack trace, I try to print them with `jstack <my_program> <core>`, but it errs as follow

```
Error: More than one non-option argument
Cannot connect to the core dump or remote debug server. Use jhsdb jstack instead
```

I also tried `jhsdb jstack --exe <my_pogram> --core <core>`, but get the following error

```
Error attaching to core file: Can't attach to the core file
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the core file
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:282)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:674)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(HotSpotAgent.java:612)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:338)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:157)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:191)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.runWithArgs(JStack.java:90)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.SALauncher.runJSTACK(SALauncher.java:297)
        at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.SALauncher.main(SALauncher.java:533)
```

Is there a way to print those ?? frames?

## Updated

After debugging the jhsdb, the cause of failure of attaching to the the core file is the interpreter cannot be located telled by the following code

```
  // now read segments from interp (i.e ld.so or ld-linux.so or ld-elf.so)
  if (read_interp_segments(ph) != true) {
      return false;
  }
```

And after reading the source code of JDK, I find the following env variable can print more information

```
{
                "name": "LIBSAPROC_DEBUG",
                "value": "DEBGUG"
            }
```